# I am having trouble with dispatching redux action from react Login component . I have tried to figure it out in vain

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to dispatch a loginAction to a redux store to update the store with the user details once a user logs in, but I am getting an error ... **TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Navigation from '../components/Navigation';
import {
    Form , Button
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from  'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getUser } from '../redux/actions';
import store from '../redux/store'

class Login extends Component {  

    handleLogin(e){
        e.preventDefault();        
        const email = document.getElementById('formEmail').value;
        const password = document.getElementById('formPassword').value;
        const user = { email, password};

        this.props.dispatch(getUser(user)) //here's where the problem is!           
       
        
    }
    render() {
        const { user } = this.props; 

        return (
            <div className="bg-light">
                <Navigation />
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="user-login-wrap">
                        <div className="user-icon">
                            <i className="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div className="bg-white p-5 shadow-sm">
                            <h4 className="text-center">Login</h4><hr />
                            <div className="p-3"></div>
                            <Form>
                                <Form.Group controlId="formEmail">
                                    <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                                    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                                    We'll never share your email with anyone else.
                                    </Form.Text>
                                </Form.Group>

                                <Form.Group controlId="formPassword">
                                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                                </Form.Group>
                                {/* <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
                                    <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
                                </Form.Group> */}
                                <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={this.handleLogin}>
                                    Submit
                                </Button>
                            </Form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({user : state.user})

// const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
//     getUser : actions.getUser
// })

export default connect( mapStateToProps, {getUser})(Login);
```

and here is my action.js file

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_USER, GET_USER_ERROR } from '../types';

export const getUser = (user) => async dispatch => {
    // return console.log(user)
    try{
        const res = await axios.post(`http://localhost:8080/users/login`, user)       
        dispatch({
            type: GET_USER,
            payload: res.data
        })
    }
    catch(e){
        dispatch({
            type: GET_USER_ERROR,
            payload: console.log(e),
        })
    }

}
```

And this is the error I get

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**

I want to dispatch an actioon to the store so that the store gets updated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw you have mapDispatchToProps commented out.  If you wanted to use it, I believe it would look like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getUser: user => dispatch(getUser(user))
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

Then you could call it with `this.props.getUser(user)`

If you can get that to work, then you can try your simplified code of directly putting in `{getUser}` in your connect wrapper.

Comment: Hi Laurenyz, I have tried that also still getting the same error

Comment: Hi Edgar256 - try turning your Login function into an arrow function: 
`handleLogin = (e) => {`. It might be a binding issue, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862192/react-typeerror-cannot-read-property-props-of-undefined) question.