# updating state with new state in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i want to make a request to my php page to retrieve data until the page is loaded. i made this request with axios' this request is successful ". i want to change state in store "the state tank is successful but the change is no".
I found an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined, at 'componentDidMount handle succes' level.

```js
the code of the error page:
import React from "react";
import Axios from 'axios';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
const mapDispatchtoprops=(dispatch)=>{
    return{
        load_state:(store)=>dispatch({type:"load_produit_to_state",payload:store})
    }
}
const mapStateToProps =(state)=>{
    return{
        state,
    }
};
class Produit extends React.Component{
      componentDidMount(){
        let request = new FormData;
        request.append("getters_produit","true");
        Axios.post('http://localhost/e_commerce/src/php/get.php',request).then(function(reponce){
            //handle succes
                this.props.load_state(reponce.data.liste_produit);
        }).catch(function(error){
            alert(error);
        }).then(function(){
            //always executed
        });
    }
render(){
    return(<div className="les_produit">
        { console.log( this.props.state), console.log( "from props")}
    </div>)}
}
```

```js
store page:
import {createStore} from 'redux';
const reducer =(state,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
       case 'load_produit_to_state':alert(action.payload); return{ liste_produit: action.payload };
        default: return state;
    }
}
const initialstate = {
    liste_produit:"none",
    profile:"nono"
}
export default createStore(reducer,initialstate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
componentDidMount(){
        const {load_state} = this.props // You Need This
        let request = new FormData;
        request.append("getters_produit","true");
        Axios.post('http://localhost/e_commerce/src/php/get.php',request).then(function(reponce){
            //handle succes
                load_state(reponce.data.liste_produit);
        }).catch(function(error){
            alert(error);
        }).then(function(){
            //always executed
        });
    }
```

### See This.

### [React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862192/react-typeerror-cannot-read-property-props-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an arrow function instead for the axios callback to preserve e context of `this`:

```
Axios.post('http://localhost/e_commerce/src/php/get.php',request).then((reponce) =>
```

Hopefully that helps!